# Pycharm does not recognize my ideavimrc (Windows)

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I am using the community version of pycharm on Windows 10 with vim. To do so I have installed IdeaVim. I have renamed my .vimrc file from my linux PC into .ideavimrc (I also tried _ideavimrc) and stored it in the directory C:\Users<my username>
When I am in pycharm at the bottom right there is even the blue-green V symbol of IdeaVim. If I press it there is the option to "Open ~/.ideavimrc .
If I do so pycharm even opens that file (even if I have named it _ideavimrc), so it clearly can FIND the file but it does not include any of the commands, key bindings or other customization that I have defined in my (idea)vimrc. What is going wrong?

Comment: Pay attention to https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#Files. What did you specify in the *.ideavimrc* file?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Judging by the syntax the link is stating infos regarding Linux, right?
I include some stuff from vundle, bin certain keys, deactivate some other keys and some other smaller stuff that helps when programming with python